# packet encoder RF packets by using LPF for determining if it's zero or one

Tags: matlab, signal-detection, correlation, preamble

[image]I'm transmitting RF packets with frequency 868MHZ ,
symbol rate (it's the same as bit rate) is 50KBaud , and Im sampling them by a dongle (fs=20480KHZ) to capture those RF packets, the captured samples are IQ RAW DATA and I save them into a file , by matlab Im using this file and plot all the captured data(packets), I see the RF packets as peaks where there's packet found, otherwise noise.

I have built demodulator which the output of its values ranges between 1 and -1 , so I have arrived to a file that has values that ranges between 1 and -1 , this demodulated IQ samples I want to convert them to binary 0 or 1 , so Im trying to build encoder in Matlab code by using LPF , how could I do that? for more clarification I want to input to my LPF the demodulated IQ samples and then the output would be something like:

[image]

I want this because if I have the output of LPF then I can walk through that output and decide where I have "zero-Crossing" this means when there's a step (zero-crossing) then the value would be changed from zero to 1 or 1 to zero (depend on the value what was before) ,

how can I do that? the cutoff frequency of my LPF  must be my bit rate frequency right? how can I also do LPF in matlab? thanks alot !!!!

second question, lets assume I have the output of my LPF , then how can I walk through the output in order to decide zero/one (deciding zero crossing-high to low or low to high-), this part called FLOW ESTIMATION , how can I do that?

Comment: any help guys??

Comment: What's the question here? You want to convert an output that takes values in between 1 and -1 to correspond to either a 0 or 1?

Comment: By the way which dongle are you using?

Comment: yes ! convert the output that takes values between 1 -1 to correspond to either 0 or 1 , using rtl sdr.dongle

Answer (score 1):

If the constellation at the tarsmitter is symmetric about 0 on the real line then you can simply threshold the output between -1 and +1 with 0 as the threshold. So anything above zero is a logical 1 and everything below zero is a logical 0.

This detection is rule is optimal when the noise is additive.

Comment: I understand you , but the problem that the data are probabilistic, this means that between the change from 1 to -1 in the demodulated vector would be values that ranges between 1 and -1 , so I'm looking for an optimal way for making the conversion from the demodulated vector to zero and 1(choosing threshold isn't good-not optimal) , my SNR isn't high ..

Comment: I could do rounding to the values that are found on the "switch" between 1 and -1 , but rounding will not help me .. need optimal way, so I chose LPF method .. for detecting zero-crossing

Comment: So if I understand, you have sampled a signal, where each sample is used to determine whether a 0(corresponding to -1) or 1(corresponding to +1) was transmitted, so in this case if a sample is 0 is transmitted and received sample is -0.563 then map it to logical 0, if the sample value is +0.126 then it's logical 1. However if you have multiple samples corresponding to a single symbol, then you can choose the last sample corresponding to the symbol

Comment: Yup you got me, 1 is logically 1 , -1 is logically 0 . I understand you but how do you know that when 0 is transmitted then the recieved sample is -0.563? maybe it's -0.7? maybe -0.2? my problem actually is mapping the vector of values that I sampled which they range between 1 and -1 to 1 and 0 ..

Comment: This is exactly the whole problem statement of a field called detection theory. In short, suppose I transmitted -1 and due to noise it shifted to let's say -0.1.the Receiver knows that the ttansitter transmits either a +1 or -1 with equal probability and the reception gets corrupted by additive gaussian noise. In this case we try to formulate a rule the "minimizes the probability of error", this is given by the log likelihood ratio, and turns out that fir this problem it will be a simple rule which gives a threshold of 0. Anything above that is a 1 and below that is a 0.

Comment: This does not mean that there will be no error in detection, ex : you could very well receive a value of +0.24 when a -1 was transmitted, the detection rule will map this to a logical 1 or anlaog +1, which would be incorrect and we would have an error. The packet would need to retrasnmitted or whatever handling is applied to handle errors

Comment: But the likelihood that if you receive anything below 0, that -1 was transmitted is higher than if +1 was transmitted. This is why we have this rule

Comment: GOT YOU ! , so my question is now how could I find an optimal way to determine that what I received is zero or one? I mean what should I do in order to succeed in optimal way to decode my packet! I mean by decode that the packet I received it (sampling it ) and the values are ranges from 1 to -1 , there's also noise yeah .. and it would also be converted to values ranges between 1 and -1 , so all what I need what should I do in order "optimally" convert my vector(received data that I get from transmitter) to zero and 1 , thanks alot.

Comment: This is just what we discussed, just compare the received vector element wise to 0, the elements that are greater than 0 are a logical 1 else they are logical 0. It's a simple Signum function operated on each of the elements of the received vector

Comment: Have in mind that if at the transmitter we associate a -1 to a logical 1 and a +1 to logical 0 then you have to correspondingly change at the receiver deciding rule itslef. Inshort reverse the rule

Comment: Im attaching a photo by matlab of what vector that Im talking about in order to convert .. there would be big errors if I convert as what you said and that's not optimal .. see my photo that I attached it on my thread (recently attached)

Comment: maybe if I have done LPF from "softing" the change (the step) between 1 and -1 ..would be more accurate?

Comment: Moreover, you said above " In this case we try to formulate a rule the "minimizes the probability of error", this is given by the log likelihood ratio, and turns out that fir this problem it will be a simple rule which gives a threshold of 0. Anything above that is a 1 and below that is a 0. " could you explain it in more simple terms? if I understand you that if we choose zero in my case then accordingly to likelihood it will give me would optimal error? I tried to understand likelihood but didn't understand that much (I mean the intuition of this formula)  , appreciated!!

Comment: Likelihood is the probability distribution function of a random variable "parameterized by" by "not random" but unknown variable. You can google it "likelihood function of a random variable". Now, the data bandwidth is 50KHz and you are sampling at 20KHz? or you meant something else?

Comment: Do you see my photo above that I attached it on the thread at first? those data that I get ranges between     
(-1 1)  , so if I understand you well if I choose my threshold 0 to say if bigger than zero => 1 else 0 would be the minimum error accordingly to likelihood probability distribution?

Comment: Yes, why don't u try that and paste a picture let's see. A stem plot would clear up the picture

Comment: Alright I will try and attach what I get

Comment: my data (what you see on photo above) im sampling on 20480K by my dongle (rtl sdr) and my bandwidth of transmitter is 98K , my symbol rate data of transmitter (bit rate data ) is 50KBaud , you asked for those information before, maybe they are related to something that you mentioned above ?