# How to check my CRC of my RF packet?

Tags: signal-analysis, digital-communications, noise, signal-detection, preamble

The "problem" is that I want to validate if my received RF packet is valid or not valid, in other words I want to validate if my RF packet corrupted or not corrupted .
the transmitter that Im using is micro controller launchpad called c1350 , so through the datasheets for the CC13xx I discovered ( in page 5, section 4) that it uses CRC32 (page 704, section 8.2.3.8). So, the implementation of crc that my transmitter cc13xx useis CRC32.... my question is:
I've the recieved packet and I know its CRC in terms of binary bits, so now how can I check by CRC if my recived packet is valid or not? my packet before transmitting "before getting to the air" wasn't having CRC .. and once transmitted "on the air" it has CRC (received packet has CRC).

what approach/algorithm should I do/implement in order to check if my received packet corrupted or not?

CRC implementation is CRC32 .

by datasheet cc13xx: [enter link description here](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/swcu117i/swcu117i.pdf?ts=1593422600898) we discover at (page 5, section 4)
It uses CRC32: [enter link description here](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/swcu117i/swcu117i.pdf?ts=1593422600898) (page 704, section 8.2.3.8).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deciding if the received packet is valid or not valid](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/68503/deciding-if-the-received-packet-is-valid-or-not-valid)

Comment: @MarcusMüller It doesn't help very much to point to a question that is closed as lacking clarity and whose sole answer is very unsatisfactory too,

Comment: @DilipSarwate point is that the comments very helpfully point out what is to be done.

Comment: @MarcusMüller but Im asking how can I check my CRC , on the other thread was figuring out what my CRC implementation is, now Im asking how can I check my CRC in order to see if my packet is valid or not ..

Comment: I don't know the transmitted CRC in order to compare with received CRC, that's my problem!

Comment: All says to compare my received CRC that I see it in my received packets, but to compare it with what? ! thanks alot for any assistance

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be much discussion of CRC in this forum but on the sister site math.SE, there are several postings. See, for example, [CRC Computation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/66117/15941) or [What is the theory behind seeding a CRC](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/66117/15941).

Comment: is that CRC calculation valid for every CRC implementation?

Comment: There are lots of bells and whistles(such as prepend a fixed sequence of characters to the data to be protected by CRC, _complement_ the first n bytes of the data before calculating the CRC etc) in specific CRC implementations which will make the calculation specified in the cited answers not quite right unless you also include the bells and whistles too.